# moving SDL video surface

Tags: c#, winapi, sdl, sdl.net

Does anyone know how to move my [SDL.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20101116002325/http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net:80/index.php/Main_Page) video surface around the screen programtically?

```
Surface videoContext = Video.SetVideoMode(1024, 768, 32, false, false, false, true, true);

var a = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(Video.WindowHandle);
var b = System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.FromHandle(Video.WindowHandle);
```

I can't find any properties in `Surface` or `Video` which do the job, and `FromHandle` is returning Null.

The window is initializing falling off the bottom of the screen.
[image]

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've seen this code but can't work out an equivilent C# implimentation. Can anyone help?

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <SDL_syswm.h>
SDL_SysWMinfo i;
SDL_VERSION( &i.version );
if ( SDL_GetWMInfo ( &i) ) {
  HWND hwnd = i.window;
  SetWindowPos( hwnd, HWND_TOP, x, y, width, height, flags );
}
```

Failing that, how much work is involved in including some c++ in my c# project?

Thanks.

Comment: notes to self: Look here for clues when you get home... http://fixunix.com/xwindows/91816-coords-window-under-sdl.html , http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=328286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need these declarations:

```
    private static IntPtr HWND_TOP = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static int SWP_FLAGS = 0x004 | 0x0010;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr after, int x, int y, int width, int height, int flags);
```

Usage:

```
    SetWindowPos(Video.WindowHandle, HWND_TOP, x, y, width, height, SWP_FLAGS);
```

where x and y are in screen coordinates.  Use Control.PointToScreen() if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the C++ code you've found, you could P/Invoke the Win32 `SetWindowPos` function and pass the `Video.WindowHandle` handle (as well as your size and position parameters) since there doesn't appear to be a solution provided by .NET.